# How to add certificate file to setting up libcurl HTTPS connection on the os which doesn't have file system?

Tags: c, ssl, curl, https, libcurl

I am trying to port libcurl to a device.

I program in C on Windows and I want to use the device to communicate with web server using HTTPS.

But I have a problem that I don't know how to add my Certificate file when setting options.

I have a .pem file, there are many certificates in it. 
And I found two `curl_easy_setopt()` options: `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and `CURLOPT_CAPATH` can set Certificate file path or directory path to `libcurl` connection.

But there is a problem: the os of the device doesn't have file system.

Are there any way to set the certificates for the HTTPS connection on the device?

Comment: No, I think that certificate file is server certificate. And libcurl will check server certificate of server's hello packet exist in the certificate file or not.

Comment: So it's the list of trusted CA :)

Comment: Yes, the file is the list of trusted CA.

Comment: When you say the device don't have a file system, it still can create ramdisk? (I guess programs are one a read-only chip?)

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "create ramdisk". The OS is on a flash memory.

Comment: Create a small temporary filesystem in the ram to put the list of CA, but if you can put it on the flash memory it's better.

Comment: It seems too hard for me to create a filesystem... Is it possible to write CA file as hardcode into libcurl?

Comment: @DanielStenberg Write that up as an answer, it should get upvotes even if the OP has not built curl using openssl, it's valuable information.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thank you for your information. I built libcurl with OpenSSL, and I need some time to try this example.

Answer (score 0):

[cacertinmemory.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html) is an example by the curl project, showing how to do it if libcurl was built with OpenSSL.

Comment: I built libcurl with OpenSSL, and I had tried this example before. It works for me! Thanks for your answer!